# What is the correct model for sequence memory?

Tags: distributions

Suppose I survey a population asking each individual to recall as many digits of pi as they can. (Assume that they get them right but only to a point. Or, alternately we can just take up to their first error, or even just ask them to report how many digits they think they know.) On the one hand we might think that this is simply Bernoulli around, say, 5 digits - some folks will remember 6, some only 3, etc. But on the other hand there is a bias toward lower numbers of digits - everyone will recall at least 1 (3), and as the number of digits rises exponentially fewer people will get to higher and higher numbers, and eventually you’ll reach zero, suggesting a poisson or discrete power distribution. What is the appropriate distribution?